# Parsing Json in Java without using a library

Tags: java, json

I have a json object here:

```
{"room":
     { "treasure":"true",
       "room":{"treasure" : "false"},
       "room":{"treasure" : "false"}
     }
}
```

I am trying to parse it so it prints to the screen in the following manner:

Cave

```
Room

  Treasure = true

  Room

    Treasure = false

  Room

    Treasure = false
```

I have been reading on JSON libraries to accomplish this, but I am not allowed to use any JSON library, can this be done or no?

Comment: How do you think someone implemented a JSON parsing library if it wasn't possible to read JSON without a library?

Comment: use these diagrams to help you : http://www.json.org/ ...a json parser is just a finite state machine...just need to figure out your state.

Comment: If you can't use a JSON library then I suppose you'd have to figure out a grammar for JSON and then tokenize it based on that.

Comment: @LoganMurphy A context-free grammar such as JSON can't be parsed by a finite state machine, no?

Comment: what do you mean by context-free? As in you can't simply read it? Recursion is necessary to maintain your context.